# Exibir imagem de acordo com a hora repetindo a função javascript

Tags: php, javascript, setinterval, settimeout

Estou usando este código para exibir duas imagens em uma determinada página:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#mapinha {
position: relative;
top: 0;
left: 0;
}
#mapa_big {
position: relative;
top: 0;
left: 0;
}
#mapa_movimento {
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="mapinha">
  <img id="mapa_big" src="http://triviapw.hiperportal.blog.br/elysium_old/images/floresta_yujia_big_v2.jpg" />
  <img id="mapa_movimento" src="" />
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Logo após a tag fechar a tag 'body' estou usando este script para determinar que imagem será exibida dentro do ID="mapa_movimento" de acordo com o minuto atual:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
var currentTime = new Date().getMinutes();

if (44 <= currentTime && currentTime < 45) {
    if (document.getElementById) {
        document.getElementById("mapa_movimento").src = "http://triviapw.hiperportal.blog.br/elysium_old/images/moves/floresta_yujia_v2_move_001.png";
    }
}
if (46 <= currentTime && currentTime < 47) {
    if (document.getElementById) {
        document.getElementById("mapa_movimento").src = "http://triviapw.hiperportal.blog.br/elysium_old/images/moves/floresta_yujia_v2_move_002.png";
    }
}
else {
    if (document.getElementById) {
        document.getElementById("mapa_movimento").src = "http://triviapw.hiperportal.blog.br/elysium_old/images/moves/floresta_yujia_v2_move_003.png";
    }
}
</script>
```

Pretendo usar uma imagem diferente para cada minuto... e isso já está ok, o problema é fazer a função repetir a cada 60 segundos para trocar a imagem exibida ao usuário.

Por exemplo, se acessar a página as 05:44 horas, será exibida a imagem "...001.png", porém quando trocar a hora para 05:55, a imagem a ser exibida deverá ser "...002.png".

Para resolver o problema, já tentei utilizar 'setInterval' e 'setTimeout', mas não funcionou, acredito que seja a falta do nome desta função que muda as imagens, porém não consegui fazer com que funcionasse quando alterei para:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function mudarImagem(){
 var currentTime = new Date().getMinutes();

if (44 <= currentTime && currentTime < 45) {
    if (document.getElementById) {
        document.getElementById("mapa_movimento").src = "http://triviapw.hiperportal.blog.br/elysium_old/images/moves/floresta_yujia_v2_move_001.png";
    }
}
if (46 <= currentTime && currentTime < 47) {
    if (document.getElementById) {
        document.getElementById("mapa_movimento").src = "http://triviapw.hiperportal.blog.br/elysium_old/images/moves/floresta_yujia_v2_move_002.png";
    }
}
else {
    if (document.getElementById) {
        document.getElementById("mapa_movimento").src = "http://triviapw.hiperportal.blog.br/elysium_old/images/moves/floresta_yujia_v2_move_003.png";
    }
}}
</script>
```

Obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para mostrar a imagem que queres **quando a página carrega** podes também fazer no servidor. Se queres que a página mude a imagem **enquanto está aberta** precisas então de JavaScript.

Nota: deves colocar a tag `<script>` não depois do fecho do `body` mas sim antes.

Podes fazer isso assim:

```js
function mudarImagem() {
  var currentTime = new Date().getMinutes();
  var img = document.getElementById("mapa_movimento");
  var base = "http://triviapw.hiperportal.blog.br/elysium_old/images/moves/";

  if (44 <= currentTime && currentTime < 45) {
    img.src = base + "floresta_yujia_v2_move_001.png";
  } else if (46 <= currentTime && currentTime < 47) {
    img.src = base + "floresta_yujia_v2_move_002.png";
  } else {
    img.src = base + "floresta_yujia_v2_move_003.png";
  }
  return mudarImagem;
}

setInterval(mudarImagem(), 30 * 1000); // atualizar a cada 30 segundos
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    #mapinha {
      position: relative;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
    }
    #mapa_big {
      position: relative;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
    }
    #mapa_movimento {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0px;
      left: 0px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="mapinha">
    <img id="mapa_big" src="http://triviapw.hiperportal.blog.br/elysium_old/images/floresta_yujia_big_v2.jpg" />
    <img id="mapa_movimento" src="" />
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, obrigado!